# What's the meaning of the result of two tensors with different shapes subtracting from each other?

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I have a tensor of shape `[batch_size, num_kernels, kernel_dim]`. Then I derive two tensors from it, one of shape `[batch_size, num_kernels, kernel_dim, 1]` and the other of shape `[1, num_kernels, kernel_dim, batch_size]`, and I subtract the second from the first obtaining a shape of `[batch_size, num_kernels, kernel_dim, batch_size]`(via numpy, tensorflow, or etc). How does this work out? What's the meaning of each dimension? For example, does `num_kernel` still means the number of kernels as the original tensor and why?

### Update:

Here's where my question emerged. It basically describes minibatch discrimination introduced by Tim Salimans et la in the paper "Improved Techniques for Training GANs".

[image]

I don't understand why the code in tensorflow successfully computes the procedure described above it. More specifically, I want to know how step 2 and 3 match the code.

Comment: Dimensions don't really have meanings, at least not out of context.  In the result the first `batch_size` corresponds to the first dimension of the first array.  The 2nd `batch_size` corresponds to last dimension of the 2nd array.  But it's you who has given that dimension some meaning or identity.  May be you derived the second array by transposing the original, maybe you did something else, and it's just a coincidence that its size is `batch_size`.

Comment: Hi, @hpaulj. I mean to make its size `batch_size`. Assuming the resulting tensor is `t`, I'm not sure whether `tf.transpose(tf.reduce_sum(t, 0), [2, 0, 1] )` is equal to `tf.reduce_sum(t, 3)

Comment: I added a test of those sum alternatives to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardest part to understand should be

```
diffs = tf.expand_dims(x, 3) - tf.expand_dims(tf.transpose(x, [1, 2, 0]), 0)
```

Things will be clear if we fix the first dimension, i.e. (For clarity, here, I use numpy notation and use `y` and `z` to represent the transformed `x`)

```
diffs[k] = y[i, :, :, 1] - z[1, :, :, :]
```

in which we have `y[i, m, n] = [x[i, m, n]]`, and `z[1, m, n, j]=x[j, m, n]`. Now we broadcast `y` and `z`, we'll have `y[i, m, n, j]=x[i, m, n]` for any `j`, and `z[i, m, n, j]=x[j, m, n]` for any `i`. For a fixed `i` and 'j', if we subtract `z` from `y`, we equivalently subtract `x[i, m, n]` from `x[j, m, n]`, which is exactly (M_{i, b}-M_{j, b} in step 2

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to give a better explanation than the one in [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), but I can try to summarize it.

The process of fitting one array to another so you can do vectorized operations between them is called "broadcasting". Broadcasting goes dimension by dimension, starting from the right. For each dimension:

- If the two arrays have the same size on that dimension… well, that one's obvious.
- If one array has size 1 on that dimension, it gets repeated.
- If one of the arrays has run out of dimensions, it's treated as if it were 1 in every remaining dimension.

For example, if you want to do `x + y`, where `x` is a 20x10 2D array:

- If `y` is also 20x10, it adds each row of `y` to the corresponding row in `x`. And, for each such row, it adds each column from the `y` row to the corresponding column from the `x` row. So, the result is 20x10.
- If `y` is 1x10, it adds the single row from `y` to each of the 20 rows from `x` and returns a 20x10 result.
- If `y` is 20x1, it adds each row of `y` to a row of `x`, by adding the single column in each `y` row to every column in the `x` row. Again, 20x10.
- If `y` is 1x1, it adds the single row of `y` to every row of `x`, by adding the single column in that `y` row to every column in the `x` row. Just like adding a scalar to `x`. Again, 20x10.
- If `y` is 10x1, this is a value error—the 1 column can be broadcast to 10 columns, but the 10 rows can't be broadcast to 20 rows.
- If `y` is a length-10 1D array, it adds `y` to each of the 20 rows from `x` and returns a 20x10 result—the same as if `y` had been 1x10.
- If `y` is 30x20x10, it each of the 30 20x10 rows of `y` to the whole 20x10 `x`, so the result is 30x20x10.
- If `y` is 30x1x1, it adds each of the 30 1x1 rows of `y` to the whole 20x10 `x`, so the result is 30x20x10.
- If `y` is 30x5x1, this is an error—the 1 can be broadcast to match the 10, and the missing dimension from `x` can be broadcast to match the 30, but the 5 can't be broadcast to match the 20.

Comment: Thx for answering, I've already known these rules. However, I'm not sure if the dimension of the resulting tensor has the same meaning as it was. An example is given in the question, another is if the two `batch_size`s in the resulting tensor both means batch size

Answer (score 0):

A simple case where two versions of the same array are subtracted is:

```
In [208]: x = np.arange(10)
In [209]: x[None,:]-x[:,None]     
Out[209]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0]])
```

`[209]` is a case of a (1,10) minus a (10,1) producing a (10,10).  In effect it is pairwise differences.

So your case might be the pairwise differences between batches.  This might be clearer (to humans) if you used:

```
[1,          batch_size, num_kernels, kernel_dim]
[batch_size, 1,          num_kernels, kernel_dim]
[batch_size, batch_size, num_kernels, kernel_dim]
```

---

To test your comment, start with distinct dimensions:

```
In [210]: x = np.arange(2*3*4*5).reshape(2,3,4,5)
In [211]: np.sum(x,0).shape
Out[211]: (3, 4, 5)
In [212]: np.transpose(np.sum(x,0),[2,0,1]).shape
Out[212]: (5, 3, 4)

In [214]: np.sum(x,3).shape
Out[214]: (2, 3, 4)
```

Shapes don't match, so the sums won't either (in general).

Comment: Hi@hpaulj, thanks for answering. I see you use different `batch_size` in the update, that's why the shapes don't match IMHO. However, I did a similar test in numpy, and indeed observe two different results. I just don't understand why they're different. I've updated my question to show you where my question emerged.

Answer (score 0):

Don't blame me if I'm wrong.

Say you have two 2d matrices `X` and `Y` with shape `(x, n)` and `(y, n)` repectively, and you want to calculute the L1-distance. You may want to do something like

```
np.abs(X[:, None, :] - Y).sum(-1)
```

or

```
np.abs(np.expand_dims(X, -1) - np.expand_dims(Y.transpose(1, 0), 0)).sum(1)
```

They produce the same result with different broadcast approaches:

1. The first one, which I think is much simpler, calculate like this,

   `(x, 1, n) - (y, n) => (x, y, n) => (x, y)`
2. The second one, which I belive is just a simple version of the code you posted, calculate like this,

   `(x, n, 1) - (1, y, n) => (x, n, y) => (x, y)`

The key point here is: for **pairwise** differences like this, in order to produce result with shape `(x, y)` you need to add an extra dimension and do some broadcasts.

For your case, `x` and `y` are both `batch_size`. If you ask about the meaning of them, I would say "the first `batch_size` means **from** and the second `batch_size` means **to**. `diffs[0, ..., 1]` is just the distance from the first sample in the batch to the second sample in the batch."